# Loading Mustache.js partials

Tags: jquery, templates, mustache, template-engine

I appear to be having a problem loading partials using the JS implementation of Mustache.

index.html:

```
<head>
...
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var view = {
            name: "Jon",
            occupation: "Web Developer",
            address:    "123 Place"
        };

        $("#templates").load("templates.html", function() {
            var template = document.getElementById('template1').innerHTML;
            var partials = document.getElementById('address').innerHTML;
            var output = Mustache.render(template, view, partials);
            $("#person").html(output);
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <p id="person"></p>
    <div id="templates" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
```

Template.html:

```
<div id="template1">
    <h1>{{name}} is a {{occupation}}</h1>
    {{> address}}
</div>

<div id="address">
    <p>The address is {{address}}</p>
</div>
```

The result is:

`Jon is a Web Developer` but the partial is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this dead thread as i just had the same issue, and think i figured it out. The html for the partial will return "&gt" instead of the '>' character. This caused the partial to not load.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass html code like that : `{{{ <h1>My title</h1> }}}`
( { } x 3 )